# Count numbers of days worked for Employees in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a database containing transactional data. I am trying to count the number of days all employees worked between '2016-03-01' and '2017-03-01'. What I am using to determine the days worked per employee is by doing a `count(distinct day(datecompleted))` where datecompleted resembles a day that an employee completed an activity as the driver.

The issue is there can be 50-100 transactions a day each having a datecompleted time stamp, however I just want to check if the employee worked that day by grabbing a distinct day(datecompleted) and then counting how many between the given time frame...

I used this query:

```
select 
    count(distinct day(dateCompleted)),
    repName
from 
    DATABASE_view_Final
where 
    datecompleted between '2016-03-01' and '2017-03-01'
group by 
    repName
```

For some reason I keep getting the result : 31....

which doesn't make any sense...someone please help

Comment: Your counting distinct days NOT dates.  change to select count(distinct dateCompleted),

Comment: You may need to use a subquery to get employees and distinct dates. Then in the outer query do a group by employee count

Comment: But within the day example April 3 there are various timestamps...as it goes down to the minute...will that make a difference?

Comment: so cast the datefield should do it as i suggested under john's answer

Answer (score 2):

Your counting distinct **days** (1-31) NOT **dates**.  Perhaps you could try:

```
select count(distinct cast(dateCompleted as date)),
repName
from DATABASE_view_Final
where datecompleted between '2016-03-01' and '2017-03-01'
group by repName
```

Comment: addendum, provided that datecompleted is date only otherwise cast as date

Comment: @maSTArHiAn Very true, I did assume date and not datetime

Comment: Hi John..what if datecompleted is in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss....will this still work on this type of date format?

Comment: @BorisD'Souza Happy to help.  It is always the little things that will get you 